# How to type dynamically imported modules with a non-literal specifier

Tags: typescript, dynamic-import

I must dynamically import modules with a non-literal specifier in a TypeScript code base and would like to strictly type the imported modules.
Because `import` return a `Promise` resolving to `any` the example does work as expected but if the imported modules would change and no longer export what was expected, the application will fail at runtime.
I understand that TypeScript can automatically type the dynamic imports when using a literal specifier, but is there a (recommended) way to statically type dynamic imports with a non-literal specifier to make sure that type errors can be found at compile time?

A minimal example would look like this:

**index.ts**

```js
const main = async (moduleName: string) => {
  const { foo } = await import(moduleName);

  console.log(foo());
};

void main("./moduleA");
void main("./moduleB");
```

**moduleA.ts**

```js
export const foo = () => "fooA";
```

**moduleA.ts**

```js
export const foo = () => "fooB";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a cast here:

```
const main = async (moduleName: string) => {
  const { foo } = await import(moduleName) as { foo: () => string };

  console.log(foo());
};
```

Comment: But how would this guarantee at compile time that the modules have the expected exports?

Comment: @doberkofler First, how would you do it at runtime?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but without runtime checks it would fail with an exception. The runtime checks would (at least) check if the property names in the imported module are available.